# Is there a service that checks PYPI packages?

Tags: python

Knowing that some pypi packages have a history of being malicious, like [libpeshnx, libpesh, and libari](https://www.zdnet.com/article/malicious-python-libraries-targeting-linux-servers-removed-from-pypi/).

Is there some website/service that labels packages as secure or not? for example: node's npm advisores https://www.npmjs.com/advisories

if not, why such service does not exist at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a package has been discovered to be malicious, it will be taken down. The npm advisories link for malicious npm packages is mostly a history if you're looking at packages to download. There isn't a need for a service to tell you whether a package you're about to download is malicious (because it would not exist).

On the other hand, when looking at currently installed packages, in npm, there's a built in feature, `npm audit`, which will tell you if the packages you're using have vulnerabilities (including known malicious packages). This is actually a newish feature, only released in the past year.

It appears this isn't built in to PIP, but there's a well known package called `safety`: https://pypi.org/project/safety/ that achieves the same functionality. It looks like this achieves your goals?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yes, this is exactly what i was hoping for.